# storage automatically get cleared in codename one

Tags: arraylist, storage, codenameone

Hi I am writing an arraylist in storage using

`private void addItemToRecentListStorage1(Hashtable h){
    Storage s1 = Storage.getInstance();
    ArrayList<Hashtable> a = (ArrayList<Hashtable>)s1.readObject("RecentItems");
    ...
    ...
    a.add(0,h);//adding on top
    s1.writeObject("RecentItems", a);
}`

If I inspect s1 immediately after adding 1st element, it shows me appropriately in storage hierarchy.

[image: 1st entry has 4 elements]

But at a time of adding 2nd element(HashTable) it clear the 1st stored hashtable values, though it shows as a blank element.

[image: before adding 2nd entry]

Means, I am getting 1 element(HashTable) in arraylist by readObject() but that hashtable's all 4 elements are wiped out. This was working earlier but now its wiping out HashTable data from arraylist.

So eachtime I am getting number of element incremented by 1 when I add element. But all previous hashtables' values are cleared.

Same thing is happening in emulator as well as device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out if you have an exception in the console that might have been triggered by serialization failing for some of the objects within the array.

Comment: sorry for late reply, I checked debugger console in output but unfortunately I didn't get any exception or warning.

Comment: But the strange thing I noticed is, when I add 1st item and close emulator then run project again and if I add 2nd item then it shows both item. So in another words, in a single run if I add multiple items then it does not read from storage. But if I close emulator and start again for each item then it reads all item (storage elements) correctly. Do you recon is there any resource holding the storage file may cause this? or within single run cursor might be pointing to one record and if I add 2nd record in storage then first record is released?

Comment: Is there a possibility of parallel use? My guess is that you have two concurrent accesses to RecentItems. One both read the single item array and both save it and one of them wins the race.

Comment: Hi Shai, it seems you are right! I did following to avoid problem and that trick worked. I added `st.clearCache();` berore storage.read() and storage.write() and that solved the problem. Thanks for support.